# findFragmentByTag returns null even though debugger shows existing fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, tablet

I'm out of ideas. I call

```
for(ImageView imageView :((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList)
{
    imageView.setClickable(true);
}
```

But `findFragmentByTag` returns null. Debugger shows this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujmwk.png)

When I go a step further, the program skips all if's and jumps to return null.

This is the log output generated by the fragmentmanager

```
04-21 19:12:27.492 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Commit: BackStackEntry{41050da0}
04-21 19:12:27.492 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:   mName=null mIndex=-1 mCommitted=false
04-21 19:12:27.492 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:   Operations:
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:     Op #0: ADD MapFragment{410504e0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:     Op #1: ADD ParkFragment{410505e8 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:     Op #2: HIDE ParkFragment{410505e8 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Run: BackStackEntry{41050da0}
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: add: MapFragment{410504e0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Allocated fragment index MapFragment{410504e0 #0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.499 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: add: ParkFragment{410505e8 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.507 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Allocated fragment index ParkFragment{410505e8 #1 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.507 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: hide: ParkFragment{410505e8 #1 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.507 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto CREATED: MapFragment{410504e0 #0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.507 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto CREATED: ParkFragment{410505e8 #1 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.507 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: MapFragment{410504e0 #0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.554 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: ParkFragment{410505e8 #1 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.906 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto STARTED: MapFragment{410504e0 #0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.914 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto STARTED: ParkFragment{410505e8 #1 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.914 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Commit: BackStackEntry{40feb250}
04-21 19:12:27.914 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:   mName=null mIndex=-1 mCommitted=false
04-21 19:12:27.914 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:   Operations:
04-21 19:12:27.921 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:     Op #0: ADD BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 btDialog}
04-21 19:12:27.921 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto RESUMED: MapFragment{410504e0 #0 id=0x7f0c0071 MAPFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.921 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto RESUMED: ParkFragment{410505e8 #1 id=0x7f0c0071 PARKFRAGMENT}
04-21 19:12:27.921 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Run: BackStackEntry{40feb250}
04-21 19:12:27.921 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: add: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 btDialog}
04-21 19:12:27.921 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Allocated fragment index BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:12:27.929 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto CREATED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:12:27.929 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:12:27.968 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto STARTED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:12:28.101 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: moveto RESUMED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.406 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Commit: BackStackEntry{420bc108}
04-21 19:13:30.406 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:   mName=null mIndex=-1 mCommitted=false
04-21 19:13:30.406 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:   Operations:
04-21 19:13:30.421 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp D/FragmentManager:     Op #0: REMOVE BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.929 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Run: BackStackEntry{420bc108}
04-21 19:13:30.937 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: remove: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog} nesting=0
04-21 19:13:30.937 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: movefrom RESUMED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.937 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: movefrom STARTED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.937 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: movefrom STOPPED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.937 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: movefrom ACTIVITY_CREATED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.937 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: movefrom CREATED: BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
04-21 19:13:30.945 26499-26499/com.example.paulforster.nxtapp V/FragmentManager: Freeing fragment index BluetoothDialogFragment{410503d8 #2 btDialog}
```

This is the whole `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.paulforster.nxtapp;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import de.amr.plt.rcParkingRobot.AndroidHmiPLT;
import parkingRobot.INxtHmi;

//TODO einzeichnen von Fremnden Gegenständen in die Karte
//TODO warum kann ich da nicht parken?
//TODO ParkIcons neben die Linie

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 154;
    static AndroidHmiPLT hmiModule = null;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAdapter;
    static BluetoothDialogFragment btDialog = null;
    static Timer refreshTimer;
    static TimerTask refreshTimerTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );
        //Kein Bluetooth --> keine App
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth ist auf ihrem Gerät nicht verfügbar! :(",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
        }
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.mode_pause:
                                hmiModule.setMode(INxtHmi.Mode.PAUSE);
                                break;
                            case R.id.mode_scout:
                                hmiModule.setMode(INxtHmi.Mode.SCOUT);
                                break;
                            case R.id.mode_park:
                                hmiModule.setMode(INxtHmi.Mode.PARK_NOW);
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Nächste Parklücke wird angefahren", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            btDialog = new BluetoothDialogFragment();
            MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            ParkFragment parkFragment = new ParkFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.content, mapFragment, "MAPFRAGMENT");
            ft.add(R.id.content, parkFragment, "PARKFRAGMENT");
            ft.hide(parkFragment);
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT");
            ParkFragment parkFragment = (ParkFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT");
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Log.e("AConPause", "onStart");

        reScheduleTimer(100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e("AConPause", "refreshTimer.cancel() happens");
        refreshTimer.cancel();
        refreshTimer = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e("AConPause", "onResume");
        //TODO wenn man gerade Bluetooth eingeschaltet hat, findet er die Liste noch nicht...
        if (!btDialog.isAdded()) if(hmiModule == null) btDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "btDialog");
        else if (!hmiModule.isConnected()) btDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "btDialog");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if(resultCode != RESULT_OK){
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    public void reScheduleTimer(int duration) {
        refreshTimer = new Timer();
        refreshTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        refreshTimer.schedule(refreshTimerTask, 0, duration);
    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    refreshMenu();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void refreshMenu(){
                    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (hmiModule != null)
                        if(hmiModule.isConnected()) {
                            Log.e("Status", "is verbunden");
                            if(hmiModule.getCurrentStatus() != null) {
                                Log.e("Status", "is da");
                                switch (hmiModule.getCurrentStatus()) {
                                    case SCOUT:
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
                                        for(ImageView imageView : ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList){
                                            imageView.setClickable(true);
                                        }
                                        fragmentTransaction.hide((ParkFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT"));
                                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                        if ((((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler != null){
                                            String data = "MSG DATA";
                                            Message msg = (((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler.obtainMessage(0, data);
                                            msg.sendToTarget();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case PARK_NOW:
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
                                        for(ImageView imageView : ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList){
                                            imageView.setClickable(true);
                                        }
                                        if ((((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler != null){
                                            String data = "MSG DATA";
                                            Message msg = (((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler.obtainMessage(0, data);
                                            msg.sendToTarget();
                                        }
                                        fragmentTransaction.show((ParkFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT"));
                                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                        /**
                                        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
                                            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                                    .beginTransaction();
                                            ParkFragment parkFragment = new ParkFragment();
                                            ft.add(R.id.content, parkFragment);
                                            ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                            ft.commit();
                                        }*/
                                        break;
                                    case PARK_THIS:
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
                                        for(ImageView imageView : ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList){
                                            imageView.setClickable(true);
                                        }
                                        fragmentTransaction.show((ParkFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT"));
                                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                        /**
                                        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
                                            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                                    .beginTransaction();
                                            ParkFragment parkFragment = new ParkFragment();
                                            ft.add(R.id.content, parkFragment);
                                            ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                            ft.commit();
                                        }
                                         */
                                        break;
                                    case PARKED:
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(false);

                                        for(ImageView imageView : ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList){
                                            imageView.setClickable(false);
                                        }
                                        fragmentTransaction.hide((ParkFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT"));
                                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                        if ((((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler != null){
                                            String data = "MSG DATA";
                                            Message msg = (((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler.obtainMessage(0, data);
                                            msg.sendToTarget();
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case INACTIVE:
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
                                        //TODO die Arraylist mit den ParkIcons muss hier immernoch existieren
                                        for(ImageView imageView : ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList){
                                            imageView.setClickable(true);
                                        }
                                        fragmentTransaction.hide((ParkFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT"));
                                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                        if ((((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler != null){
                                            String data = "MSG DATA";
                                            Message msg = (((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler.obtainMessage(0, data);
                                            msg.sendToTarget();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
                                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
                                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                            }
                        }
                }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (hmiModule != null && hmiModule.connected) {

            terminateBluetoothConnection();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Terminate the bluetooth connection to NXT
     */
    private void terminateBluetoothConnection(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth connection was terminated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        hmiModule.setMode(INxtHmi.Mode.PAUSE);
        hmiModule.setMode(INxtHmi.Mode.DISCONNECT);
        hmiModule.disconnect();

        while(hmiModule.isConnected()){
            //wait until disconnected
        }
        hmiModule = null;
    }
}
```

Someone having a hint for me? Thank you!

**EDIT**
Error happens no longer.
My goal was to make device-rotation possible. I did some undo's/changes which can be found in this [commit](https://github.com/hockeymanesv/HSAMR/commit/c7057b6078bf2a489e470f8aa7bd67ca332a733f).

Maybe someone has a clue what happens.

Comment: Interesting. I can't see why the debugger would skip those lines. Tags seem to match, nothing is `null`. The only thing I can think is that it's something to do with how `FragmentManager` is working asynchronously. You can call `enableDebugLogging` on a `FragmentManager`. Perhaps that might give you some vaguely useful information.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for the hint Michael. May you help me to unterstand the log? (look in the edited question)

Comment: Please provide the version of the appcompatActivity that you are using from buid.gradle

Comment: @ChaitanyaAtkuri com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after committing the fragment transaction(ft.commit() in onCreate).

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

*Calling commit() does not perform the transaction immediately. Rather, it schedules it to run on the activity's UI thread (the "main" thread) as soon as the thread is able to do so. If necessary, however, you may call executePendingTransactions() from your UI thread to immediately execute transactions submitted by commit(). Doing so is usually not necessary unless the transaction is a dependency for jobs in other threads.*

Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions for details regarding executePendingTransactions.

Comment: Sadly this does not work. I also think, that onCreateView and refreshMenu both are executed in the ui-thread, so i don't understand how this could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void refreshMenu(){
                    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
List<ImageView> imageViewList = ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT")).imageviewArrayList;
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (hmiModule != null)
                        if(hmiModule.isConnected()) {
                            Log.e("Status", "is verbunden");
                            if(hmiModule.getCurrentStatus() != null) {
                                Log.e("Status", "is da");
                                switch (hmiModule.getCurrentStatus()) {
                                    case SCOUT:
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(false);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
                                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
                                        for(ImageView imageView :imageViewList){
                                            imageView.setClickable(true);
                                        }
                                        fragmentTransaction.hide((ParkFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PARKFRAGMENT"));
                                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                        if ((((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler != null){
                                            String data = "MSG DATA";
                                            Message msg = (((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAPFRAGMENT"))).mHandler.obtainMessage(0, data);
                                            msg.sendToTarget();
                                        }
                                        break;
```

The issue I suspect in your code is that your beginTransaction with FragmentManager and in between you are querying it for FindFragmentByTag, hence I moved it onto the top of the beginTransaction. Make similar changes in all the places used and let me know your feedback

Comment: Sadly it still return null. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Have you tried, finding the fragment by Id instead of Tag??